# In laravel 6, when I'm using logoutOtherDevices(), other devices got logout but redirected to login page. How can I change it to home page?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using Custom authentication and middleware but when using logoutOtherDevices function its working but redirecting them to /login. And i want to redirect them to home page i.e /home

Comment: `Authenticate.php` middleware you can add `return url('/');`  or add your code

Comment: `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`  => `return route('login');` to `return route('/');`

Comment: have done it already but still redirecting to /login.

Comment: Add your custom auth code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the unauthenticated method that are extendble class of app/Exceptions/Handler.php, this file is the default file of laravel that handle when the session expired. To solve that just write this code in your app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('YOUR ROUTE HERE'));
}
```